# Javascript: How do you invoke a function which has parameters

Tags: javascript

As part of a validate onsubmit function, I wish a function isFilled(var str) to be invoked. However, it is failing to be invoked successfully and as a result the validateForm() function is terminated prematurely.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function validateForm(){
    ...
    alert(isFilled("bla bla bla"));
    ...
}

function isFilled(var str){ // checks that the given string isn't empty
    if(str == "" || str == " "){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Furthermore I am not being informed by the browser's console of the error. Should I wrap my code in try/catch statements? If so, how?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here. I think more information is needed, like the code omitted from the validation function. I think you're focusing on the wrong spot.

Comment: I agree with @Carcigenicate.  You're not giving us a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see this construction: `function isFilled(var str) {` first time. Is it OK? I mean `var str` as a parameter

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var` because you don't need to declare the function's argument.

Comment: @nvioli Whoops, missed that somehow lol. Ya, that might cause a problem. He said the console isn't reporting any errors though.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring function arguments is incorrect in javascript. Corrected code:

```
function isFilled(str){ // checks that the given string isn't empty
  if(str == "" || str == " "){
      return false;
  }else{
      return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to declare a variable in a function parameter.  Just give it a parameter name

str can be called whatever you want it to be:

```
function isFilled(parameter){ // checks that the given string isn't empty
    if(parameter == "" || parameter == " "){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```